# express checkout with html info without API calls?

Tags: paypal

Can I improve user experience, e.g. show product description, and highlight "Pay using your credit card", with simple Paypal buttons?

I offer a paid **service** on my website, with monthly **subscription**, fixed amount each month. I don't need the user's address, and there's only 1 "product".

Currently I created a simple "paypal button", which works fine, but I want to improve it, and possibly make it even shorter, but didn't find out how to:

1. highlight "pay with credit card",
2. I don't want to force users into logging into their paypal account (users with paypal account get error: "You cannot use an e-mail address or card number that belongs to an existing PayPal account")
3. show the user the product details/descriptions as in the picture:

   [image]

Although I'm a programmer, I prefer not to use any API calls, especially since it doesn't seem to be necessary in my simple case.

- How can I add these elements?
- Is there an option with paypal to send users directly to a credit-card payment screen?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to switch to the Express Checkout API to show item details and force the credit card option.  Even then, though, if the user has the credit card added to a PayPal account they're going to have to sign in and pay that way rather than use the CC form.  Also, if you're working with recurring payments they'll need a PayPal account anyway.

The only way to avoid that is to sign up for PayPal Payments Pro so you can tie the credit card form directly into your website with no redirect to PayPal at all.

You'll need to enable Recurring Billing on Pro, too, after it's approved and enabled, and then your users can choose to sign up with PayPal (where you'd use Express Checkout) or Pro (where they'd enter a credit card directly.)

If you're really that set on not using API's you could apply for Enhanced Recurring Payments for Payments Standard, but I haven't fully tested that to see about passing order item details to the review pages.